# Filtrar consulta por fecha y tipo de registro

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo una tabla en la que registro cliente ,fecha de pago ,tipo deuda o pago (D y P) y su valor.

TABLA :

```
CREATE TABLE pagos_detalles (
  cliente varchar(100),
  fechapago DATE NULL,
  tipo varchar(1),
  valor decimal(14,2)
);
```

Registros

```
INSERT INTO pagos_detalles (
  cliente,fechapago,tipo,valor
) VALUES(
  'Elian','2018-07-23','D',80.50
),(
  'Elian','2018-08-23','D',80.50
), (
  'Roberto','2018-08-23','D',80.50
), (
  'Roberto','2018-08-23','P',80.50
), (
  'Anderson','2018-08-24','D',80.50
),  (
  'Robert','2018-08-24','D',80.50
), (
  'Robert','2018-08-24','P',80.50
), (
  'Luz','2018-08-26','D',80.50
), (
  'Luz','2018-08-26','P',80.50
)(
  'Luz','2018-09-26','D',80.50
), (
  'Luz','2018-09-26','P',80.50
);
```

Trato que me filtre los registros de los clientes que tengan una deuda o pago el mismo mes y solo me liste los que tengan deudas o pagos sin cruzarse.

la verdad es la primera ves que me topo con algo asi y no se por donde empezar, si me pueden dar un indicio lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Deberia quedar Elian y Anderson verdad?

Comment: Que quieres decir con "sin cruzarse", edita tu pregunta y pon un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 0):

No se si es lo que requieres, pero puedes obtener los registros filtrando por `tipo y fecha de pago`. En la condicional `Where` le indicamos que nos traiga los registros donde tipo sea `D o P`, en fecha de pago solo ingresas la fecha a consultar, esta debe ser en el formato correspondiente.

Estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE pagos_detalles (
  cliente varchar(100),
  fechapago DATE NULL,
  tipo varchar(1),
  valor decimal(14,2)
);

INSERT INTO pagos_detalles (cliente,fechapago,tipo,valor) VALUES('Elian','2018-07-23','D',80.50),
('Elian','2018-08-23','D',80.50),
('Roberto','2018-08-23','D',80.50),
('Roberto','2018-08-23','P',80.50), 
('Anderson','2018-08-24','D',80.50), 
('Robert','2018-08-24','D',80.50), 
('Robert','2018-08-24','P',80.50), 
('Luz','2018-08-26','D',80.50),
('Luz','2018-08-26','P',80.50),
('Luz','2018-09-26','D',80.50), 
('Luz','2018-09-26','P',80.50);
```

---

**Consulta**

```
SELECT * FROM pagos_detalles WHERE TIPO IN ('D','P') AND 
 fechapago = '2018-08-23';
```

| cliente | fechapago | tipo | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Elian | 2018-08-23 | D | 80.50 |
| Roberto | 2018-08-23 | D | 80.50 |
| Roberto | 2018-08-23 | P | 80.50 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Dime si te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

he estado jugando con tu base de datos por que me ha parecido muy interensate la consulta.

Aquí va mi solución, basàndome en que lo que quieres es filtrar por cliente/fecha/valor para saber que cliente tiene una deuda abierta o si por el contrario ya ha saldado su deuda (mediante el pago de la misma).

Dicho esto, empezemos.

Si haces la clàssica consulta de "muestramelo todo"

```
SELECT * FROM pagos_detalles
```

| Cliente | FechaPago | Tipo | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Elian | 2018-07-23 | D | 80.50 |
| Elian | 2018-08-23 | D | 80.50 |
| Roberto | 2018-08-23 | D | 80.50 |
| Roberto | 2018-08-23 | P | 80.50 |
| Anderson | 2018-08-24 | D | 80.50 |
| Robert | 2018-08-24 | D | 80.50 |
| Robert | 2018-08-24 | P | 80.50 |
| Luz | 2018-08-26 | D | 80.50 |
| Luz | 2018-08-26 | P | 80.50 |
| Luz | 2018-09-26 | D | 80.50 |
| Luz | 2018-09-26 | P | 80.50 |

Para agrupar las filas i verificar si `tipo = "d" i "p"` al mismo tiempo...
Podemos hacer varias cosas i de diferentes maneras, te explico una de ellas:

**Por ejemplo**: agrupar por cliente, fecha i valor ( i concatenar la columna tipo ).

```
SELECT cliente, fechapago, group_concat(tipo), valor
FROM pagos_detalles
GROUP BY cliente, fechapago, valor
```

Esto nos daria esta respuesta:

| Cliente | FechaPago | Tipo | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anderson | 2018-08-24 | D | 80.50 |
| Elian | 2018-07-23 | D | 80.50 |
| Elian | 2018-08-23 | D | 80.50 |
| Luz | 2018-08-26 | D,P | 80.50 |
| Luz | 2018-09-26 | D,P | 80.50 |
| Robert | 2018-08-24 | D,P | 80.50 |
| Roberto | 2018-08-23 | D,P | 80.50 |

La podemos poner un poco más bonita:

```
SELECT cliente, fechapago, GROUP_CONCAT(tipo) AS tipoGroup, valor,
CASE GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)
WHEN "d,p" THEN "Sin deuda"
WHEN "d" THEN "Deuda abierta"
ELSE "Solo pago? que? donacion? Error!"
END AS Resumen
FROM pagos_detalles
GROUP BY cliente, fechapago, valor
```

Que nos daría esto:

| Cliente | FechaPago | TipoGroup | Valor | Resumen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anderson | 2018-08-24 | D | 80.50 | Deuda abierta |
| Elian | 2018-07-23 | D | 80.50 | Deuda abierta |
| Elian | 2018-08-23 | D | 80.50 | Deuda abierta |
| Luz | 2018-08-26 | D,P | 80.50 | Sin deuda |
| Luz | 2018-09-26 | D,P | 80.50 | Sin deuda |
| Robert | 2018-08-24 | D,P | 80.50 | Sin deuda |
| Roberto | 2018-08-23 | D,P | 80.50 | Sin deuda |

Entonces si lo que quieres es, por ejemplo, mostrar solo los que tienen una deuda abierta, lo haces con una subconsulta i filtras por tipoGroup.

Lo que sería hacer esto:

```
with subconsulta as (
    SELECT cliente, fechapago, GROUP_CONCAT(tipo) as tipoGroup, valor,
    CASE GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)
    WHEN "d,p" THEN "Sin deuda"
    WHEN "d" THEN "Deuda abierta"
    ESLE "Solo pago? que? donacion? Error!"
    END AS Resumen
    FROM pagos_detalles
    GROUP BY cliente, fechapago, valor
)
SELECT * FROM subconsulta
WHERE tipoGroup = "d"
```

Ésto nos da la tabla con solo los que tienen deuda sin pagar, osea esto:

| Cliente | FechaPago | TipoGroup | Valor | Resumen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anderson | 2018-08-24 | D | 80.50 | Deuda abierta |
| Elian | 2018-07-23 | D | 80.50 | Deuda abierta |
| Elian | 2018-08-23 | D | 80.50 | Deuda abierta |

**Espero que sea de tu ayuda, lo ha sido para mi buscar esta solución!**

Si necesitas alguna otra consulta que no sea exactamente esta y no te sales con la tuya, comentamelo y la sacaremos adelante! :)

En estas consultas, hay que entender que solo da como "pagada" una deuda que se esté abriendo y cerrando el mismo día.

Si quieres que conste como pagada una deuda del mismo mes, pudes hacer los mimo pero agrupar y mostrar por `month(fechapago)`  o `monthname(fechapago)` en vez de simplemente `fechapago` .

Un saludo!